# How does the grammar and phonology of a language affect poetry in this language?

Tags: phonology, grammar, poetry

How does the grammar and phonology of a language affect poetry in this language? Can it encourage using particular rhyming schemes and meters while making other rhyming schemes and meters impossible? It would be nice to see some real examples.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: guifa, I've edited to make it more clear

Comment: In every way possible. That's a lot of ways. To see some examples (mostly from English but occasionally from German and Portuguese), try the poetics papers on [Haj Ross's page](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/).